# (Eclipse RCP) How to redirect the output to Console View?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have two viewers, one has a Text for user's input and the other viewer is the Eclipse's built_in Console View. And I will run an java program according user's input, and want to display the log information in the ConsoleView. Does anybody know How can I redirect the output to Console View ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SO questions [How to write a hyperlink to an eclipse console from a plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591018/how-to-write-a-hyperlink-to-an-eclipse-console-from-a-plugin) and [writing to the eclipse console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716615/writing-to-the-eclipse-console/716883#716883) give example of redirection to the Console.

The blog post [Displaying the console in your RCP application](http://dev.eclipse.org/blogs/wayne/2006/10/19/displaying-the-console-in-your-rcp-application/)

[image]

The ideas remain to create an `OuputStream` and open a New `Console`, or associating the `MessageStream` of a console to `stdout` adn `stderr` (like my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716615/writing-to-the-eclipse-console/716883#716883))

Comment: I follow your method, but unfortunately the Log Message will show in Console, but the output from System.out can not show in Console.

Answer (score 1):

Redirect output on **RCP** console:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.eclipse.e4.ui.di.Focus;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.DisposeEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.DisposeListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class ConsoleView {
    private Text text;

    @PostConstruct
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        text = new Text(parent,
                SWT.READ_ONLY | SWT.MULTI | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);

        OutputStream out = new OutputStream() {
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            @Override
            public void write(final int b) throws IOException {
                if (text.isDisposed())
                    return;
                buffer.append((char) b);
            }

            @Override
            public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
                super.write(b, off, len);
                flush();
            }

            @Override
            public void flush() throws IOException {
                final String newText = buffer.toString();
                Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        text.append(newText);
                    }
                });
                buffer = new StringBuffer();
            }
        };

        System.setOut(new PrintStream(out));
        final PrintStream oldOut = System.out;

        text.addDisposeListener(new DisposeListener() {
            public void widgetDisposed(DisposeEvent e) {
                System.setOut(oldOut);
            }
        });
    }

    @Focus
    public void setFocus() {
        text.setFocus();
    }
}
```

The screenshot:

[image]